# How to implement a WPF ViewModel with PRISM INavigationAware instantiated as a resource in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I tried to implement the INavigationAware interface in my ViewModel and instantiated the ViewModel as a resource in XAML explained here
https://blog.rsuter.com/recommendations-best-practices-implementing-mvvm-xaml-net-applications/ like this sample:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Namespace.MySampleView" ...> 
    <UserControl.Resources> 
        <viewModels:MySampleViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" /> 
    </UserControl.Resources> 
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}"> 
        ... 
    </Grid> 
</UserControl>
```

But using this implementation the INavigationAware Methods in the ViewModel are not called on navigating to or from the view.
One solution is to set the DataContext of the View (UserControl) in Code-Behind.

What's best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

The methods from `INavigationAware` are called, when you *navigate* to the view model, i.e.

- you define a region (a `ContentControl` for example),
- register a view for navigation with the `IContainerRegistry`
- and then use the `IRegionManager` to navigate the region to the view.

Example:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MyRegion"/>

containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MyView, MyViewModel>();

regionManager.RequestNavigate( "MyRegion", "MyView" );
```

... and now `MyViewModel.OnNavigatedTo` will be called (given `MyViewModel` implements `INavigationAware`)...

As a side note, some of the "best practices" linked are really horrible.

Comment: I added the link especially to explain the used "View model instantiation and assignment". Here Rico Suter recommends that the view model should be instantiated in XAML in the Resources element of the root element. Then it is bound to the DataContext property of the child element of the view’s root element. So you can use features as code completion and IntelliSense in XAML.

Comment: This in particular is dubious advice, as code completion and intellisense can be achieved through setting the `DesignDataContext` without interfering with view model creation. Secondly, forcing the view to create its view model prevents you from using the view as `DataTemplate` for a view model instance that you already have a.k.a. view model-first. Thirdly, the view model must not have dependencies if the view creates it (as the view itself is created by the framework not your container), unless you resort to the `ServiceLocator` abomination.

Comment: Do you know a better best practice tutorial for WPF MVVM view and view-model creation?

Comment: The prism docs are a start, of course, and there should be several plural sight courses on prism. I think one of the very first points of contact for me once upon a time was this https://brianlagunas.com/building-ig-outlook-part-1setting-up-the-prism-application/